# ASP.NET what raises "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Just receiving the following error now and then in IE when loading one of my pages.

> A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly.  If
>   it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

The page does take a long time to load, and basically list a bunch of products, which is displayed in nested repeaters.

I am just wondering what is the best way to trouble shoot this bug ?

And what prompts this bug, is it page load time, an infinite loop, etc..

EDIT : I just noticed the page loads pretty much instantly in firefox, so must be an IE thing.

Comment: The error is from IE's JavaScript engine usually. It can occur if there is a lot of data coming into the page and/or a lot of data being parsed by JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop running this script, IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667456/stop-running-this-script-ie7)

Comment: I noticed this bug only occurs in IE where the page takes 10 secs or so to load but instantly in firefox. Any ideas why this would happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JavaScript executes more than a set number of statements without yielding (returning from a function), IE will throw up this dialog.

The maximum number of consecutive statements is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles\MaxScriptStatements` and defaults to 5,000,000.

Comment: Hey josh I also just noticed this slow page loading only occurs in IE, and pretty much instant in firefox. So would this be likely an IE javascript issue ?

Comment: What version of IE?  Firefox has a much faster JS engine than IE≤8.

Comment: In IE7 and IE8 it takes 3/4 times as long to load as in firefox

Comment: There's your answer.  Old IE [takes longer](http://robert.penz.name/122/javascript-engines-comparison/) to execute script.  It's clear you have some severe client-side performance issues; you might want to revisit your design.

Comment: So this issue is related to some innefficient JS or Jquery on my page ?

Comment: Yes.  Pretty much the only thing that causes this dialog to pop up is a long-running script (usually a long loop).

Comment: Even I am Facing the same problem here.So I have to change my script.?